# Android & Ormlite: Inserting data in DatabaseHelper onCreate

Tags: android, ormlite

I am using Ormlite for the first time and I am trying to setup my DatabaseHelper to insert rows after creating the database's tables.  I am getting a `getWritableDatabase called recursively` error when I do.

Here is my onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {

    try {
        TableUtils.createTable(databaseType, connectionSource, User.class);

        // Add test user
        User test = new User("test", "12345");
        getUserDao().create(test);


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Unable to create databases", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that @karnage was using an older version of [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) that had a bug with using the DAOs in the onCreate -- the pattern that he is using.  This was fixed in version 4.6 (10/2010) and downloading and running the latest version works for him.

Here is the bug report:

> https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3117883&group_id=297653&atid=1255989

Here's the change log file to track new features and versions of [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/):

> http://ormlite.com/changelog.txt

Comment: But @gray, according to the changelog, latest version is 4.48, despite there are artifacts in the maven central repository for 4.6, 4.7, 4.8 and 4.9 (which have earlier timestamps than 4.48 ?? )

Comment: 4.48 is much newer than 4.9 @DavidSantiagoTuriño.  It goes 4.9, 4.10, 4.11, ..., 4.48.  It's how maven does numbering unfortunately.